# Spring session management SessionDestroyedEvent not thrown

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security, session-management

I have a customized `RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy` and Im using `CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy` with `exceptionIfMaximumExceeded = false`.

I have the following scenario:

- login on browser #1
- login on browser #2

I want that the first session will be destroyed but they both stay active.
whan I reach the `SessionRegistry.registerNewSession` session #1 is set has expired but I never get a `SessionDestroyedEvent` for it.

security.xml

```
<security:session-management
            session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" />

    </security:http>


    <bean id="sas"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy">
                    <constructor-arg ref="clusteredSessionRegistryImpl" />
                    <property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
                    <property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="false" />
                </bean>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
                    <constructor-arg ref="clusteredSessionRegistryImpl" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

Comment: And you won't... As there is no way to invalidate the `HttpSession` from another `HttpSession`. Only the `invalid` flag in the `SessionRegistry` will be toggled.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for the answer, so now I have 2 active sessions? Is there a way to destroy the older one? It seems I'm still loged in in the old one